# When or while in the sentence

Tags: conjunctions

> They found a cat **when/as/while** they were walking in the forest.

I think “when” is better because for me it means they walked before and after finding the cat. Am I right here?

Comment: They all have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I think an English teacher is going to prefer you to use `while`, but it partly depends on whether there is more to the sentence, or not.

The basic meaning of `when` `as` and `while` are the same in this context, and are all fairly commonly used.